# LaTeX - How to keep parts in the table of contents

Tags: latex

I want to create section without numbers using the command \section*{Section Name}, but doing this omits them from the table of contents. The same thing happens using \part*{Part Name}. Is there a way to omit the section number and keep the section title in the table of contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a line to the toc with this command:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Your Title}
```