# How can I remove the numeration of some titles in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I'm writing my degree project report using the article class and I want a structure like this:

Abstract
Introduction
1. What
2. Where
3. Etc.

I was searching and I found that using [`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581916/how-do-you-extend-article-document-class-in-latex) the complete numeration is eliminated. And if I use `*` these sections don't appear in the table of content. So what can I do? Can this be done without installing packages (like memoir)?

**Note:**

[It was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459298/latex-how-to-keep-parts-in-the-table-of-contents), but I did not find it when I searched. Sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
\section*{Foo and Bar}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foo and Bar}
```

Comment: +1 for providing the code needed to make the section appear in the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `*` version of the section commands might help.  Try `\section*{Abstract}` and see if it is close enough.